# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied problem. (pagerTabIndicatorOffset)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-material3

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val tabItems = listOf("Diziler", "Filmler", "Keşfet", "Profil")
            val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            ButtomNavigationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(){
                    Column() {

                        TabRow(

                            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                            containerColor = Malibu,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(all = 20.dp)
                                .background(color = Color.Transparent)
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)),
                            indicator = {
                                tabPositions ->  TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
            /////////THIS IS THE PART OF PROBLEM(pagerTabIndicatorOffset)///////////////
                                Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState = pagerState, tabPositions = tabPositions)

                                    .width(0.dp)
                                    .height(0.dp)
                                )
                            }
                        ){
                            tabItems.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                                val color = remember{
                                    Animatable(Denim)
                                }
                                LaunchedEffect(
                                    key1 = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                                ){
                                    color.animateTo(if (pagerState.currentPage == index) Color.White else Malibu)
                                }
                                Tab(
                                    text = {
                                        Text(title ,
                                            style = if (pagerState.currentPage == index)
                                                TextStyle(
                                                    color = Denim,
                                                    fontSize = 18.sp
                                                )
                                            else TextStyle(
                                                color = Denim,
                                                fontSize = 16.sp
                                            )
                                        )
                                    },
                                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                                    modifier = Modifier.background
                                        (
                                        color = color.value,
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)
                                    ),
                                    onClick = {
                                        coroutineScope.launch {
                                            //we have to call this inside a coroutine
                                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                        }
                        HorizontalPager(
                            pageCount = tabItems.size,
                            state = pagerState,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Blue)
                        ){page ->
                            Text(
                                text = tabItems[page],
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp),
                                color = Color.White
                            )

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

my question about the problem :

I dont know what to do. I searched and I found some documents but I am a learner. So I dont know what to do exactly to fix it. So can you give me solution code or explain it detailed way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is similar issue found at Github. Apparently, it's caused by different namespace of the TabPosition. One is `androidx.compose.material3` and the other one is `androidx.compose.material:material` https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1076